# Change the azimuth of Graticule lines

Tags: qgis

I have created polygon graticule and I used ''polygons to lines'' to change the polygons into lines.
I want to change their azimuth to make them more feet into my polygons.
I had the idea to calculate the azimuth and then to find a tool to change the angle of the graticule according to the azimuth. I used this formula for the calculation-

```
degrees(azimuth(start_point($geometry), end_point($geometry)))
```

the problems are-

1. The calculated Azimuth is very weird, for most of the lines I got zero and in some I got numbers as you can see here-
   [image]
2. seems like the lines didn't break very well, this is what happen when I use ''select'' and click on one line-
   [image]
3. I don't find a tool that can help me to change the azimuth.

***My end goal is to have those lines fit to my polygons as much as possible.if you have any other -more-simple idea of how to create this net inside my polygons. please share with me***

Comment: What will the net be used for? Display purposes/printing? Spatial analysis?

Comment: in the end I suppose to be able to locate stations according to the squares that will be created. I thought to change it into polygon after finding the azimuth and ''move '' it

Comment: If you want a rotated grid, the GRASS tool v.mkgrid can do that.